# PosZInt and PosInt in scala?

Tags: scala, int, scalatest

In ScalaTest [configuration.scala](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.prop.Configuration), methods are taking `PosInt` rather than `Int`. eg: `MinSuccessful(value: PosInt)` What's the difference among them?

My research on line shows that they belong to `Anyvals`. How does that benefit the scala test process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are just small wrappers around ints that verify at compile-time that the value is positive (or non-negative for PosZInt). [See the documentation here.](http://doc.scalactic.org/3.0.1/#org.scalactic.anyvals.PosInt)

The purpose is to prevent you from doing, for example, `MinSuccessful(-1)`.